# Replace one font with another in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

So, for a touch of context, most of the web uses aliased Gulim as their Korean font of choice - see a comparison between that and antialiased/hinted Nanum Gothic here:

[image: Unhinted gulim vs hinted nanumgothic]

The former is rather painful to look at, so I'd like to replace used instances of Gulim with Nanum Gothic (via JS through user scripts, CSS through Stylish, or whatever other method would be effective). Things I've tried:

- Chrome's Advanced Font Settings extension to change the default Korean font - most sites using Korean text ignore it.
- Direct font-family replacement on * from Stylish just overwrites *all* fonts.
- Font-family descriptors with unicode-range specified (still overwrites all fonts so there's no fallbacks for the stuff outside of korean codepoints)
- JS override of font family on load - most pages don't explicitly specify Gulim, or any default Korean font really, for some reason (and this is probably the cause of the first attempt with the font settings extension failing).

Enabling font smoothing on Gulim would be an acceptable but not ideal solution. Since a massive shift in the use of Korean font choices is outside the scope of my skills, any suggestions as to how I can solve this from a consumer's perspective?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to really change a font with a new one on the hard way in Css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'MyFontName';
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   src: url("./myFont.file"); /*this can be an url*/
}
body{
   font-family: 'MyFontName';
}
```

Comment: I believe this question is about changing a single font selectively (Replace Gulim with Nanum); wouldn't this replace the font family of the entire document?

Comment: @dotVezz I'm wondering that myself, but as long as it only overrides Gulim I don't care. Going to test it when I get a chance.

Comment: yes this will only change the font-family of the document. I don't think you can replace a default font in another way.

Comment: Update: This works wherever a webpage explicitly specifies Gulim as a font family. Some pages - see Google - do not do this, and the override doesn't work. Works as a partial solution, at least :P

Comment: If you use !important like  `font-family: 'MyfontName' !important;` in the body the problem persist?